# maximum number of links in bipartite network

Tags: networking, graph-theory, bipartite

Consider a bipartite network with `N1` and `N2` nodes in the two sets, what is the maximum number of links the network can have, and  how many links cannot occur compared to a non-bipartite network of size `N = N1 + N2`

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of links of a bipartite graph:
N1 * N2
where N1 and N2 represent the cardinality of each respective node set (number of nodes in each partition).

The maximum number of links without the constraint of being bipartite (a complete graph):
(N(N-1))/2

Now take the difference.

Answer (score -1):

maximum number of links : N1 + N2

how many links cannot occur compared to a non-bipartite network of size :

N = N1 + N2

N*(N-1)/2